# data structure (or array) {XYZ}- if X is distinct, and Y meets conditions, calculate with Z?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Having a lot of trouble figuring this one out, and appreciate any hints (LINQ maybe?).

I have a data structure that comes from a CSV string list

```
data[i].X = Convert.ToSingle(dataList[0]);
data[i].Y = Convert.ToSingle(dataList[1]);
data[i].Z = Convert.ToSingle(dataList[2]);
```

The data is from an image, so each X has many Y (with a corresponding Z), for example:

```
X: 0 0 1 1 2 2
Y: 0 1 0 1 0 1
Z: 1 2 3 2 1 0
```

I need to find all the Z values that match a distinct X (where Y will be between certain values).  I have converted the data structure to a double array for doing some maths, so I've tried

```
distData[0] = distTemp[0].Distinct().ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < distData.Length; j++)
            { 
                if (data[i].Y > 0 && data[i].Y < 2 && data[i].X == dist[0][j])
                    dist[0][i] = data[i].Z;
            }
        }
```

this works, but now I don't have the foggiest notion how to work with the data i'm given.  I'm returned what i should expect, which is a huge array (data.Length) that has some 0 values, then a group of Z values (when the conditions are met), then 0, and so on.

```
0 0 0 0 Z Z Z Z Z 0 0 0 Z Z Z Z 0 0 0 0 0 Z Z...
```

What i need to do next is group the non-zero data, so for above I want "average the first group of Z, ignore the 0's next, average the next group of Z..." so I end up with a Z average (and other calculations) for each unique X value that meets the Y value conditions.

I have no ideas how to do that logic, and it seems from the very basic LINQ I've used on my data structure (i'm very new to LINQ) that there may be a better way than a lot of array iterations - assuming i can even figure out the iteration logic.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to collect `n` out of `n` available valuess, then using an array of size `n` and only filling the values you want to collect seems like a bad idea. Because that’s exactly what you are doing with `dist[0]`: Every `Z` which should be collected gets set to its index at `dist[0][i]`; for all other `Z`, you do not change the array value.

Instead, you should just collect those values you are interested in:

```
var values = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    if (condition(data[i].Y))
        values.Add(data[i].Z);
}
```

Afterwards, `values` will contain all those `Z` for which the condition on `Y` was successful. Of course, this dramatically changes how the resulting data structure will look like, moving away from the input data structure, but that’s what you should do: Take the input data and transform it in the way you need to do.

And then, it’s also quite simple to express that with LINQ:

```
var values = data.Where(d => condition(d.Y))
                 .Select(d => d.Z)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks!  i've sorted out the X,Y,Z indexes now and it works great (and is much faster as well)